# Group by and count with join across tables?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.6. I have a table of assets:

```
CREATE TABLE assets (
    name varchar,
    company_number varchar
);
```

And a table of companies (the `company_number` in the two fields is related, though there is no formal foreign key) - a company can have many assets:

```
CREATE TABLE companies (
    company_number varchar primary key,
    name varchar
);
```

And a table of company directors, with a foreign key to companies - a company can have many directors:

```
CREATE TABLE directors (
    id serial primary key,
    company_number varchar REFERENCES companies(company_number),
    person_name varchar
);
```

I can get a ranked list of which directors are involved in the most companies simply, as follows:

```
SELECT person_name, count(*) AS num_companies 
  FROM directors 
  GROUP BY person_name
  ORDER BY num_companies DESC;
```

And I can get a ranked list of the number of assets owned by each director as follows (I *think* this is correct):

```
SELECT q.person_name, count(*) as num_assets FROM
(SELECT a.name, c.company_number, c.person_name AS person_name
    FROM directors d
    LEFT JOIN assets a
    ON a.company_number=d.company_number) q
GROUP BY q.person_name ORDER by num_assets DESC;
```

But how would I get both in one command? In other words, I'd like a full list of directors, with both the number of companies they are involved in, and the number of assets those companies control.

UPDATE: as requested, here's example SQL for creating the tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE assets (
    name varchar,
    company_number varchar
);
INSERT INTO assets VALUES ('foo', 1), ('bar', 1), ('baz', 2), ('bar', 2), ('fii', 3);
CREATE TABLE companies (
    company_number varchar primary key,
    name varchar
);
INSERT INTO companies VALUES (1, 'acme corp'), (2, 'intergalactic holdings inc'), (3, 'intergalactic shellco inc');
CREATE TABLE directors (
    id serial primary key,
    company_number varchar REFERENCES companies(company_number),
    person_name varchar
);
INSERT INTO directors(company_number, person_name) VALUES (1, 'arthur dent'), (1, 'trillian'), (2, 'ford prefect'), (3, 'ford prefect');
```

And these are the results I'd like to get:

```
person_name,num_companies,num_assets
ford prefect,2,3
arthur dent,1,2
trillian,1,2
```

Comment: Please create sample data using http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=765222fd826584bac50716f974ebecef and post desired output

Comment: @lad2025 thanks, I struggled a bit with that site (can't work out how to clear state in a fiddle, or edit a new fiddle!) but have posted an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like a full list of directors, with both the number of companies they are involved in, and the number of assets those companies control

If I correctly understand, you need something like this:

```
select directors.person_name, count(distinct directors.company_number) as company_count, count(distinct name) as asset_count
from directors
join assets
on directors.company_number = assets.company_number
group by directors.person_name;
```